# How to create React Modal that doesn't have any overlay?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using React and Semantic UI for my website and I'm looking to create a modal popup to provide some action items on the page.

Currently, with Semantic's Modal, you must choose between three dimmer options (Default, inverted and blurring). In my case, I want the pop-up to appear, but I don't want ANY overlay. The page behind the model should appear as normal. Strangely, this isn't easy/obvious to implement.

On my page, I have the following example model code.

```
    <Modal dimmer="inverted" size='mini' open={this.state.modalopen} onClose={this.onClose}>
      <Modal.Header>Select a Photo</Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Content image>
        <Modal.Description>
          <p>Some contents.</p>
        </Modal.Description>
      </Modal.Content>
    </Modal>
```

The three options (default,inverted and blur) obviously don't work.

I have tried using styling to set the background color to transparent and other optoins, but nothing seems to work.

```
  <Modal style={{backgroundColor: "transparent"}} dimmer="inverted" size='mini' open={this.state.modalopen} onClose={this.onClose}>
```

I know there must be an easy solution here..what is it?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is used to be possible to set `dimmer={false}`, but this is deprecated (see link below) according to the documentation, and you will need to use styling in order to make it transparent, so your solution is close to what you need to do. If you inspect the rendered Modal, you'll see that you need to override the `background-color` of the `.ui.dimmer` css class. You should be able to do that in your component's stylesheet.

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/2882